# 1с отладка "НаСервере" у клиента

Tags: отладка, 1с

1с 8.3.9. Отладка на сервере включена. Использую толстый клиент. В управляемых формах отладка работает только в функциях/процедурах "НаКлиенте", "НаСервере" почему-то пропускает. Где что включить? Мне на стороне клиента нужно включить отладку сервера.

Comment: http://www.k3-67.ru/knowledge_base/47

Answer (score 1):

Если база серверная, то необходимо в реестре сервера 1С изменить/добавить возможность отладки.

```
Останавливаем службу 1C:Enterprise 8.2 Server Agent
```

Ищем в реестре следующее: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\1C:Enterprise 8.2 Server Agent\ 
Смотрим значение параметра ImagePath 
(оно имеет примерный вид: "C:\Program Files\1cv82\8.2.10.82\bin\ragent.exe" -srvc -agent -regport 1541 -port 1540 -range 1560:1591 -d "C:\Program Files\1cv82\srvinfo") 
Добавляем -debug и сохраняем: 
"C:\Program Files\1cv82\8.2.10.82\bin\ragent.exe" -srvc -agent -regport 1541 -port 1540 -range 1560:1591 -d "C:\Program Files\1cv82\srvinfo" -debug